# Create another table TRANS_TEMP from TRANSACTION table by change the column name acc_no to account_no

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

table name = TRANSACTION, i want to create another table trans_temp from transaction table but rename column acc_no to account_no. this all operation made in one query, Thank you...

Comment: What exactly is the question? What are you trying and what results are you getting vs. what results do you expect?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `CREATE ... AS SELECT` syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE trans_temp AS
SELECT
    acc_no AS account_no,
    tr_date,
    amt,
    type_of_tr,
    mode_of_pay
FROM transaction
```

The name of the columns returned by the query will become column names in the new table.

Note that the CTAS syntax does not take care of transferring constraints or indexes on the target table. You would need to recreate them manually aferwards.

Answer (score 1):

There is another method if you don't want to list out all the columns:

```
create table trans_temp as
    select *
    from transaction;

alter table trans_temp modify acc_no account_no <type goes here>;
```

Perhaps you don't need a temporary table at all, and a view would suffice.